# cd to correct folder in package.json

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

My project structure is like this:

- Project

  - client
  - server

Im trying to start both my Node Express Server & React project concurrently. But only the express server is starting. I can't figure out how to cd to /client.

**This is my package.json in /server/package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "podifi",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "client": "cd client && npm run start",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "dev": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
```

What should it be instead of: `"client": "cd client && npm run start",` ??

Comment: I would expect what you've posted to work - it does [for me](https://github.com/textbook/cyf-app-starter/blob/7ed846f0cfea766b7136368ef78f9f1d1650ead4/package.json#L25), I don't think the `./` is crucial.

Comment: Is there a package.json file in `client/`?

Comment: You may try full path.

Comment: I dont have a package.json out side both client & server like you @jonrsharpe. It's in the server folder. Should make another package.json outside these folder like you? Is that a better approach?

Comment: So where in the project structure are you running that command?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to go one folder up first

```
  "scripts": {
    "client": "cd ../client && npm run start"
  },
```

I would recommend to have a 3 `package.json` files.
One in `server` one in `client`, and one in root project.
From there you start both of them, and also you can have dependenceis for each one in part.

Comment: Ah ok. That is a better approach to it? What should be in the package.json outside /client & /server?

Comment: Your common start scripts. maybe deploy scripts. Some info about project. Maybe some common git hooks

Answer (score 0):

I think your file is ok, are you sure you're not running npm start inside the client folder? you should be outside

This is what my config looks like:

```
"start": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"yarn server\" \"yarn client\""
```

hope it helps